# Now i want to display the specific data form that listview into another listview using the ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, json, listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

```
String url = "http://example.com/bilal/fetchparty.php";
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(1, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONArray("data");
            cid = new String[ja.length()];
            cname = new String[ja.length()];
            username = new String[ja.length()];
            name1 = new String[ja.length()];                 //for size
            timetaken = new String[ja.length()];
            link = new String[ja.length()];
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject job = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                cid[i] = job.getString("cid");
                cname[i] = job.getString("cname");
                username[i] = job.getString("username");
                timetaken[i] = job.getString("timetaken");
                link[i] = job.getString("link");

                if (cid[i].equals(shared1.sp1.getString("pid", null)) && cname[i].equals(shared1.sp1.getString("title", null))) {

                    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    hashMap.put("cid", cid[i]);
                    hashMap.put("cname", cname[i]);
                    hashMap.put("username", username[i]);
                    hashMap.put("timetaken", timetaken[i]);
                    hashMap.put("link", link[i]);
                    arrayList.add(hashMap);



                    Toast.makeText(Vote.this, username[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    nameCall (username);

                }

            }

            String[] from = {"username", "timetaken", "link"};
            int[] to = {R.id.tvUsername, R.id.tvTime, R.id.tvLink};
            SimpleAdapter sa = new SimpleAdapter(Vote.this, arrayList, R.layout.vote, from, to);
            lvVote.setAdapter(sa);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

    }
});

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Vote.this);
requestQueue.add(sr);

lvVote.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        bi = link[position];
        Toast.makeText(Vote.this, bi, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});







}

private void nameCall(final String name[]) {

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, name);
    lvVoteNow.setAdapter(adapter);
    bVoteSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int p;
            String s;
            p = lvVoteNow.getCheckedItemPosition();
            if (p != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                s = name[p];
                Toast.makeText(Vote.this, "You voted for " + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //use s here
                s = null;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Vote.this, "Please Give Your Vote", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

I fetch the data from the online server and display the data into the ListView using the *simpleAdapter*. Now i want to display the specific data form that Listview into another Listview using the ArrayAdapter
    But it is displaying the whole list not according the if condition in the second ListView i.e lvVoteNow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my code

```
public class Vote extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lvVote,lvVoteNow;
    TextView tvUsername,tvTime,tvLink,cidVote,cnameVote;
    List<String> testUserName = new ArrayList<>();

    Button bVoteSubmit;
    String bi;
    String [] cid,cname,username,timetaken,link,name1,name2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vote);

        lvVoteNow = findViewById(R.id.lvVoteNow);
        bVoteSubmit = findViewById(R.id.bVoteSubmit);

        tvUsername = findViewById(R.id.tvUsername);
        tvTime = findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
        tvLink = findViewById(R.id.tvLink);
        cidVote = findViewById(R.id.cidVote);
        cnameVote = findViewById(R.id.cnameVote);

        lvVote = findViewById(R.id.lvVote);
        lvVote.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        final Shared shared1 = new Shared(getApplicationContext());
        cidVote.setText(shared1.sp1.getString("pid", null));
        cnameVote.setText(shared1.sp1.getString("title", null));

        //fetching data for vote

        String url = "http://example.com/bilal/fetchparty.php";
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(1, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONArray("data");
                    cid = new String[ja.length()];
                    cname = new String[ja.length()];
                    username = new String[ja.length()];
                    name1 = new String[ja.length()];                 //for size
                    timetaken = new String[ja.length()];
                    link = new String[ja.length()];
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject job = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                        cid[i] = job.getString("cid");
                        cname[i] = job.getString("cname");
                        username[i] = job.getString("username");
                        timetaken[i] = job.getString("timetaken");
                        link[i] = job.getString("link");

                        if (cid[i].equals(shared1.sp1.getString("pid", null)) && cname[i].equals(shared1.sp1.getString("title", null))) {

                            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                            hashMap.put("cid", cid[i]);
                            hashMap.put("cname", cname[i]);
                            hashMap.put("username", username[i]);
                            hashMap.put("timetaken", timetaken[i]);
                            hashMap.put("link", link[i]);
                            arrayList.add(hashMap);

                            Toast.makeText(Vote.this, username[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            testUserName.add(username[i]); // add userName to list
                           // nameCall (username);
                        }
                    }
                    //after all specific users add on list to this
                    String[] stringArray = testUserName.toArray(new String[0]);
                    nameCall(stringArray);

                    String[] from = {"username", "timetaken", "link"};
                    int[] to = {R.id.tvUsername, R.id.tvTime, R.id.tvLink};
                    SimpleAdapter sa = new SimpleAdapter(Vote.this, arrayList, R.layout.vote, from, to);
                    lvVote.setAdapter(sa);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Vote.this);
        requestQueue.add(sr);

        lvVote.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                bi = link[position];
                Toast.makeText(Vote.this, bi, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void nameCall(final String name[]) {

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, name);
        lvVoteNow.setAdapter(adapter);
        bVoteSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int p;
                String s;
                p = lvVoteNow.getCheckedItemPosition();
                if (p != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    s = name[p];
                    Toast.makeText(Vote.this, "You voted for " + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //use s here
                    s = null;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Vote.this, "Please Give Your Vote", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: it is showing error in  testUserName(username[i]);  saying method call expected